# Python, How to denormalise CSV file to Nested Json

Tags: python, json, csv

I currently have a CSV file with the header:
`productCode | code | dataFields.0.category | dataFields.0.name | dataFields.0.code | ...` with dataFields[n] up to 9.

When I convert the code to Json i get:

```
{
"Example": [
    {
            "exCode": "example_code",
            "name": "ex",
            "code": "ex_2",
            "dataFields.0.category": "EXAMPLE",
            "dataFields.0.name": "exampl",
            "dataFields.0.code": "exampl",
            "dataFields.0.unit": "v",
            "dataFields.1.category": "EXAMPLE",
            "dataFields.1.name": "exampl2",
            "dataFields.1.code": "exampl2",
            "dataFields.1.unit": "e",
            "dataFields.2.category": "EXAMPLE2",
            "dataFields.2.name": null,
            "dataFields.2.code": null,
            "dataFields.2.unit": "e",
    }]
}
```

However, I'm trying to convert the CSV to look like:

```
{
"Example": [
   {
    "exCode": "example_code",
    "name": "exampl",
    "code": "exampl",
    "dataFields": [{
      "category": "EXAMPLE",
      "name": "exampl",
      "code": "exampl",
      "unit": "v"
    },
    {
      "category": "EXAMPLE",
      "name": "exampl2",
      "code": "exampl2",
      "unit": "e"
     }
}]
}
```

I have been writing this project on Python without using recursion to look at least 2 levels of nesting deep into a nested json array to
remove the normalised fields and add in denormalised (nested) fields. However, my main problem is that "dataFields" will get overwritten instead of adding multiple "dataFields" elements.

This is what I have so far:

```
def denormalize_json(json_list):
    for children in json_list:
        for inner_children in json_list[children]:
            # print("Arr: ", inner_children)
            for innest_child in inner_children:
                
                split_norm = innest_child.split('.')

                if len(split_norm) == 2: # If it is only a singular nested field
                    # Add correct field
                    changes_arr.append([children, inner_children, split_norm[0], split_norm[1], innest_child])

                elif len(split_norm) == 3: # If it is normalized with more than one field
                    changes_arr.append([children, inner_children, split_norm[0], split_norm[2], innest_child])
                    
    print(changes_arr)              
    # Make changes to json_list
    for i in range(len(changes_arr)):
        changes = changes_arr[i]

        # change inner children to correct fields
        # add correct fields
        try:
            inner_children = changes[1]
            inner_children[changes[2]].append(changes[3].append(inner_children[changes[4]]))
            del(inner_children[changes[4]])
            json_list[changes[0]] = inner_children
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.